# Spring 3 with Tiles 2.2 - Templates don't show

Tags: java, spring, tiles

I am newbie at Spring 3 and Tiles 2.2.2.  I was following Spring documentation on http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/view.html to configure Tiles but the templates don't show at my test page.

Here is my **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>livros</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>formulario-login.jsp</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <filter>
     <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>encoding</param-name>
         <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

... this is my **spring-context.xml**

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ResourceBundleViewResolver">
      <property name="basename" value="views"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean class="br.com.coldsoft.livros.interceptor.AutorizadorInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>


    <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
      <property name="definitions">
        <list>
          <value>/WEB-INF/tiles-defs.xml</value>
        </list>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**tiles-defs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="layout"
        template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Controle de Livros" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/templates/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/templates/body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/templates/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="main" extends="layout">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Main"></put-attribute>
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/main.jsp"></put-attribute>
    </definition>    
</tiles-definitions>
```

**layout.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Titulo Controle de Livros -->
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>

<body>
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="body" />
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
</body>
</html>
```

**views.properties**

```
main.(class)=org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
main.url=main
```

When I access `http://myserver:8080/livros/main` it only shows the content of
this main.jsp

```
<div class="container">
    <h3>Bem vindo, ${usuarioLogado.login}!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!</h3>
</div>
```

How can I show the templates I have created on layout.jsp (they are at WEB-INF/templates) ??

Please help me out!!

Comment: Are you seeing the content of main.jsp ?

Comment: Yes, this is the only thing that it shows in the browser

Answer (score 2):

replace the `viewResolver` by:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver"
      id="tilesViewResolver">
     <property name="viewClass"
               value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
</bean>
```

and remove the `InternalResourceViewResolver`

Comment: I have replaced the viewResolver but the problem continues... what should I do next ?

Comment: Ralph, I have removed the `InternalResourceResolver`, but now my application raises this error: `javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'formulario-login' in servlet with name 'springmvc'`.  What do you think ?  Thanks for you help

Comment: Ralph, when I comment this tag: `<mvc:interceptors><bean class="br.com.coldsoft.livros.interceptor.AutorizadorInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>` on spring-context.xml, tiles works.  I would like to keep using the interceptor. Can I use tiles with interceptor ?

Comment: jamesfrj: I never have had heard about this interceptor. And google has one 3 hits in spainish, so I can not help you.